# Java program finding another technique.print (1 to 50) in 5 rows and 10 column

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean-expression

```
(1) 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) 
    { 
        System.out.print(i); 
        if ((i %10=0) 
            System.out.println(); 
    } 
} 
***************************************... 

(2) 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) { 
        System.out.print(i); 
        if ((i == 10) || (i == 20) || (i == 30) || (i == 40) || (i==50) { 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
}
```

In (2) program i want to use loop or something else where (i==j),.where j contains values 10,20,30,40,50.

```
if(i==j){ 
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

I want to do such because if i want to print from 1 to 100 
then i have to type(i==10)(i==20)(i==30) .. till(i==100).

so I want to use loop in if boolean statement if(i==j) where j can be a loop having values of j=j+10

I hope you understand my question.

Comment: what is the type of j? Where have you defined j in above code?

Comment: can use `j=10; if(i == j) { j += 10; s.o.p(\n); }`

Comment: Modulo operator `%`? if (i % 10 == 0) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

Here are 4 ways of doing it.
All 4 versions use `printf("%2d ", i)` to print result nicely aligned, like this:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

First, a corrected version of your #1, where comparison was fixed to use `==`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
    if (i % 10 == 0)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Second, a version that will use `i == j` for ending the lines, which I believe is what you were looking for.

```
for (int i = 1, j = 10; i <= 50; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
    if (i == j) {
        System.out.println();
        j += 10;
    }
}
```

Third, a way to do it using two nested loops, using a separate `num` variable for the value to be printed.

```
for (int i = 1, num = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++, num++)
        System.out.printf("%2d ", num);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Fourth, another way to do the two nested loops, without a separate variable for the value to be printed.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i += 10) {
    for (int j = i; j <= i + 9; j++)
        System.out.printf("%2d ", j);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        char c = i % 10 == 0 ? '\n' : '\t';
        builder.append(i + String.valueOf(c));
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: formatting required if (i<=10000) . is foramt possible with this  method

Answer (score 0):

This way you don't have to write all the conditions (`i == 10`, `i == 20` ...):

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    for (int i = 1, j = 10; i <= 50; i++) { 
        System.out.print(i); 
        if (i == j) { 
            j += 10;
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    }
}
```